# how to delete only specified part of a file in c?

Tags: c, file

I have written my own cp function which copies only half of the mp4 file from one partition to my own additionally created partition. This additionally created partition is half of the size of mp4 file and i am playing mp4 file from this partition.
After this half mp4 file is played, i want to remove the blocks of this part of a file so that I can copy the rest of the file to this partition and play it. 
I am using low level i/o functions open,read,write,close in C file handling to write cp function.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please post the code.

Comment: show code, state problem.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is going to be dependant on the OS you are using. I am not aware of a universal way to do this. On windows, you can use the function [_chsize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk925tyb.aspx) in unix based systems you want [ftruncate()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate). you can use each of these functions to set the size of the file to 0, effectively getting rid of your allocated blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `mmap(2)` for that purpose and get rid of the scratch partition. On most systems, this is way faster since disk I/O is handled in the fashion that is just like swap file, which is very highly optimized and accerlerated.

When start playing, map the first portion of the file to a memory address and start working from that. Then when the end of the current part is coming map the next part in.

Comment: mmap would let you write over the other sections of the file, but it would not get rid of them which is what the OP asked. In practice it may make more sense to do that, but it all depends on why he is copying half of the file in the first place.

Comment: @SE The overwriting behaviour can be prevented by open the file read-only and map the memory read-only. That will prevent any writing. `mmap(2)` allow you to map only part of the file.

Comment: @MaxthonChan...actually I am new to this mmap(2) concept. What i get it is that first I should create a file in my new partition, create mappings of original media file and this new file, copy half of media file using something like mmcpy and then starts playing this new file. Then using ftruncate, truncate this new file and again repeat the same procedure. Please clarify as I am new to this concept.

Comment: @MaxthonChan....how this will be better than doing simple i/o i.e copying half of the media file,playing,truncating and then copy the rest half. I know using memory mapped file will be faster but how exactly it can be done for my problem. thanx

Comment: @MaxthonChan I know you can mark it read only, thats not the point. you can't delete part of a file with the mmap function was my point. as for this application, I don't know that memory mapped IO would be any better than just reading sequentially with a sufficiently sized buffer since video playback doesn't require random access to a file.

Comment: @user269270 You map the original file directly, and (partially) unmap and remap the file with a different offset when needed. No copying, no scratch partition/file. Main memory is your scratch space here.

Comment: @SE OP is not actually deleting content from a file - he copied it and deleting stuff from the scratch copy, which is not needed with `mmap(2)` since you can unmap/remap with a new offset.